# Dealing with changes on complex data with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let's say I have a Service that provides a `BehaviorSubject` to any component that wants to get the latest version of some data.

```
export class DataService {    
    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<Data>(this.data);
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
}

export class Component implements OnInit {

    message:Data;

    constructor(private data: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(
        message => {
          this.message = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message))
        }
      )
    }
}
```

The Data is complex:

```
class Data {
    id:number
    prop1:string
    prop2:Array<{prop1:number, prop2:string}>
}
```

The Data changes over time, and the components are only concerned with the latest version of the data. My question is: How can the components know what exactly *changed* about the data when they get notified?

For example, let's say that only one field of one item in `prop2` changed. Every component will get the new data, but they don't know what exactly changed. Knowing what changed would open up many opportunities for rendering optimization.

Is there a built-in way to do this with BehaviorSubject? Is the component supposed to figure out the differences after it gets notified? How is this usually done?

Comment: This isn't an RxJS concern. However, if you treat the data held by the subject as immutable, you will get what want for free if you use Angular's `OnPush` change detection.

Comment: @cartant `OnPush` seems to be very useful, but what do you mean that I'll get what I want for free? I still have to check what the differences are, right?

Comment: If you compose your components hierarchically such that each piece of data is passed to a component as an `Input`, Angular will do all of the checking for you. Managing change detection is a responsibility of Angular's, so let it do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the job of `Subjects` to care about the type of their payload, let alone what properties have changed.

There are other tools to `diff` objects, e.g. you might want to check [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce) of the `lodash` library which could suit your need. If you search for `deep diff` on the web or here on Stackoverflow you'll find some more info on that matter.

Regarding your particular issue, you could store the most recent `Data` in your components and everytime you receive a new one via your subject you *diff* it with a tool of your choice, apply your changes and overwrite the stored `Data` with the latest one.